# How to get the name of the new object's constructor in the function? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm really new to the JavaScript sooo...

I have a class:

```
var warrior = function(HP) {
    this.health = HP;
}
```

And when I create a new warrior:

```
var somebody = new warrior(50);
```

I'd like to give the name "somebody" to the new element. How can I do it?

Comment: You'd have to pass it in, `var somebody = new Warrior(50, 'somebody');` and change the class to `var Warrior = function(hp, name){ this.health = hp; this.name = name; };`

Comment: I have a restriction that the call shoud look like how I wrote, but the task uses the caller name in a later function...

for example
var battle = new Battle(one, two);
battle.getWinner(); // should return "one"

Comment: You could do something like, warrior.prototype.name; then go somebody.name = "somebody";

Comment: Yeah, but it's not gonna work for any name I give to the new warrior

Comment: Why does the battle need to return the string `"one"`? Why can't it just return the full `one` object/instance/whatever you want to call it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Variable names are meaningless to the program functionality. If you care about the name, use a string and pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```js
var warrior = function(HP) {
    this.health = HP;
}

warrior.prototype.name;

var somebody = new warrior(50);

somebody.name = 'somebody';

console.log(somebody);
```

Comment: Sorry I am not fully understand the question, are you talking about being able to reference the the object somebody via a different name? Or are you talking about every instance of warrior having the name somebody?

Comment: I can create a warrior with any name I want and I'd like to use the name in an other function.

Comment: Thing is somebody already is the name of the element, that is how you are accessing it? Every new warrior will be var bob = new warrior(50); var john = new warrior(100); Those are the element names that you either pass to a function or if you are evil it is global and you can access it in the function via said name